# how to multi conditionally sort values using vba

Tags: vba, sorting, date

So I'm pulling data from an external source which returns Date strings of the given format: "10/26/2013 9:46:46 AM"

When I sort the data it does not seem to be able to distinguish between AM and PM values so many noonish / 1 AM values are moved towards the bottom. Has anyone dealt with this before / have a solution to make it recognize the AM/PM aspect along with the day and time?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just splitting the date and time using TimeValue() and DateValue() excel functions.I then wrote a macro to do a 3 key sort based on ticker, date, and then time.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is sorting this as text.  It may depend on how the data is getting pulled through.
If you select one of the cells and press F2 (to edit) then enter to go to the next cell, does this change your data?

Comment: I'm pulling the data from bloomberg so i'm using a reference to a certain ticker to pull the data, so yes I think the value is a string.. I was wondering how I can work around this w/o having a time consuming nested sort function

Answer (score 0):

In the code that is pulling the data through, you just need to amend it slightly.
Range("D5").value = string

It may change it slightly to maybe 24 hour time depending on your computer settings

Comment: Should have asked - did you write the ticker?  If not, you may be able to use a worksheet_change event and on each update a macro will run to convert the data.  Let me know if the data is pulled through in a block, or if it's constantly updated line by line.  Also what Column are the dates in?